# Amplify `tokenRefresh` event triggered multiple times

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm using the following code to monitor the auth process with Amplify+Cognito:

```js
const handleHubEvent = useCallback((capsule) => {
  const event = capsule?.payload?.event;

  try {
    switch(event){
      case 'signIn_start':
      case 'signIn':
      case 'tokenRefresh':
        const user = await auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        setCurrentUser(user);
        break;
      case 'signOut':
      case 'tokenRefresh_failure':
        setCurrentUser(null);
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error: ", e);
    setCurrentUser(null);
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  Hub.listen('auth', handleHubEvent);
  Hub.dispatch('auth', { event: 'signIn_start' });

  return () => Hub.remove('auth', handleHubEvent);
}, []);
```

The problem is that after a few hours (I guess once the session expires), the event callback `handleHubEvent` gets invoked continuously, around 7 times a second. I can see in the network tab multiple (successful) requests to `cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`.

I can also confirm `Hub.listen` is only executed once, so there shouldn't be multiple event listeners for the same event.

Even after refreshing the page, the behaviour is the same, the only way to get rid of it is by deleting the cookies and sign in again.

Is there anything obviously wrong I'm doing here?

Thanks.

Comment: any luck on your problem ?